# how we can find regular expression for following strings

Tags: finite-automata

Find regular expressions representing the following set:

1. The set of all strings over {a,b} in which the number of
   occurrences of a is divided by 3.
2. The set of all strings over {0,1} beginning with 00

Comment: http://regexr.com is a great way of playing around with regular expressions. It even has a reference

Comment: Please read about homework questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and update your question.

Comment: do you mean "number of occurrences of a which is divisible by 3"?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw out a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) and use that to find the regular expression.

For example, for `1.`, it would be
[image]

Then you use convert this into a regular expression. [This is one way](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you need an expression that gives every possible way of having a string over {a,b} with the occurrences of a divisible by 3.  There can be 0 a's since 0 is divisible by 3.  There can be 3 a's, 6 a's, 9 a's, and so on.  An expression for this is (b*ab*ab*ab*)*+b*.  The second term allows for the possibility of 0 a's and any amount of b's since 0 a's is divisible by 3.  The first term accounts for all other possibilities of strings with a number of a's divisible by 3.

For 2, the set of all strings over {0,1} is (0+1)* and if it must begin with 00, then the regex is simply 00(0+1)*